# Rails 7: How to I call foreign key model columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In previous versions of rails I could call a secondary model's columns like:
book.author.name

Now I get this error.

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: thing_statuses.thing_id
```

_thing.html.erb

```
<div id="<%= dom_id thing %>">
  <p>
    <strong>Status:</strong>
    <%= thing.thing_status.status %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <%= thing.name %>
  </p>
</div>
```

app/models/thing.rb

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :manufacturer
  has_one :thing_status
  has_rich_text :note
  has_many_attached :images
end
```

app/models/thing_status.rb

```
class ThingStatus < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :things
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `has_one` relationship to `belongs_to`, and make sure you have `thing_status_id` column for `Thing`

`belongs_to` is where the foreign key is.

`has_one` or `has_many` is on the opposite side of belongs_to

```
# Table name: things
#
#  id               :integer(11)    not null, primary key
#  thing_status_id  :integer(11)    not null
#  ...
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :thing_status
end
```

```
# Table name: thing_statuses
#
#  id               :integer(11)    not null, primary key
#  ...
class ThingStatus < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :things
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I know it was a delayed response, but the solution fixed it right away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```rb
class ThingStatus < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :thing
end
```

and a `thing_id` in the `thing_statuses`-table

Comment: I don't want to create a different status for each thing. I have 3 statuses: active, pending, complete. What you are suggesting would create a record for each thing in the thing_status table.

Comment: Do you need a history or the current status? With a history you need to edit `has_one :thing_status`  to `has_many :thing_statuses` 

If `ThingStatus` is nothing more as a key, I would add an enum to `Thing`

`enum network: %i[active pending complete]`